# Generic way of converting scipy result to a dictionary

Tags: python, scipy

To convert DescribeResult(nobs=10, minmax=(0, 9), mean=4.5, variance=9.166666666666666, skewness=0.0, kurtosis=-1.2242424242424244) to a `dictionary` so that it can be persisted to MongoDB I plan to convert using:

```
from scipy import stats
a = np.arange(10)
stats_result = stats.describe(a)
print(stats_result)

stats_dict = {}
stats_dict['nobs'] = stats_result[0]
stats_dict['minmax'] = stats_result[1]
stats_dict['mean'] = stats_result[2]
stats_dict['variance'] = stats_result[3]
stats_dict['skewness'] = stats_result[4]
stats_dict['kurtosis'] = stats_result[5]
print(stats_dict)
```

which prints:

```
DescribeResult(nobs=10, minmax=(0, 9), mean=4.5, variance=9.166666666666666, skewness=0.0, kurtosis=-1.2242424242424244)

{'nobs': 10, 'minmax': (0, 9), 'mean': 4.5, 'variance': 9.166666666666666, 'skewness': 0.0, 'kurtosis': -1.2242424242424244}
```

Is there a cleaner, more idiomatic method of converting the result to a dictionary instead of explicitly assigning each value to the dictionary based on the value index location?

`dict(stats_result)` returns an error:

```
TypeError: cannot convert dictionary update sequence element #0 to a sequence
```

Answer (score 1):

To make a dict from 2 lists, `zip` them:

```
In [3]: dict(zip(['a','b','c'],[1,2,3]))
Out[3]: {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
In [4]: {k:v for k,v in zip(['a','b','c'],[1,2,3])}
Out[4]: {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the for loop -

```
Keys = ['nobs', 'minmax', 'mean', 'variance', 'skewness', 
'kurtosis']
count = 0
#
for key in Keys:
    stats_dict[key] = stats_result[count]
    count += 1
print(stats_dict)
```

Comment: Note: The benefit will increase as the number of keys increase. In other words, benefit of for loop is directly proportional to the number of keys :)